# Data validation in constructor

Tags: c#, validation, constructor

I have a constructor that need to validate passed data.

```
public Rational(int m, int n)
```

If `n == 0` i should inform user about that.
I know 3 ways to do that.

1) Just make `return;` in coustructor
2) Generate an exception
3) Create a static method that will create an object

```
r = new Rational();
r = Rational.GetObject(1,2);
```

What is the best way to validate data in constructor?

Comment: Note, by the way, that `Rational` should probably be an immutable `struct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the constructor. 
(Making sure to specify the parameter name in addition to the exception message)

In addition, you can also make a static `TryCreate` method:

```
public static bool TryCreate(int m, int n, out Rational result);
```

or

```
public static Rational? TryCreate(int m, int m);
```

This method would return `false` or `null` if the parameters are invalid instead of throwing an exception; similarly to `int.TryParse`.

Comment: I don't get this. If you throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException in a ctor you would have to wrap the class creation in a try/catch block otherwise the exception would be un-handled. I thought class methods rather than class setup should be in a try/catch block? or have I missed something?

Comment: @Canacourse: Huh? There is nothing wrong with throwing exceptions in a ctor.

Comment: Lets say I have an application that is crashing and want to log all exceptions including ones thrown in constructors.  To catch and log an exception thrown in a ctor wouldn’t I have to create the class as follows: try{SomeClass someClass  = new SomeClass("somedata");} with a corresponding catch block?  Otherwise the exception would be unhandled and not logged.

Comment: @Canacourse: If you want to log all exceptions, handle the appropriate event.  Don't add `catch` blocks everywhere.

Comment: In general, you should only ever use a `catch` block if you can actually handle the exception and do something useful.

Answer (score 8):

Considering you're dealing with an invalid argument being passed into the constructor, I would probably throw a new `ArgumentException` from inside the constructor.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @JSBangs @SLaks - Indeed I did mean ArgumentException. Either that or, as Mark Byers mentioned, ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: My teacher said that Exception in coustructor is very bad way. He said to do it as a 3rd way

Comment: @Sergey Gavruk - If it's a pattern that Microsoft follows (throwing Exceptions from constructors), I'm not going to feel too bad doing it myself. Check out the List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) constructor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx and look at the Exceptions it will throw.

Comment: It is a pretty common practice in .net development to throw exceptions in constructors if the arguments do not satisfy some invariant rule.  This works even better if the class is immutable.  I think I remember hearing something about this being a problem in C++, but that is outside of my area of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

- Throw an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) in the constructor.
- Validate the value the user enters before calling the constructor and generate a suitable error message. The exception should be a last resort.

Comment: Validate data before constructor should user that usees my class. But he may dont know about it

Comment: @Sergey Gavruk: That's why you have both mechanisms - your users *should* validate all inputs but if they forget to do this then your code will fail early and give them a helpful error message so that they can see how to fix their code.

Comment: Many people don't like exceptions in contructor. They say that it is very bad way

Comment: @Sergey, it is worse to have an object in an invalid state and use it as if it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Generate an exception: you can't afford to let the user play with (create) an object that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with throwing an `System.ArgumentException` from the constructor.